# which do you choose to put FK?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

Is it right or interchangeable if FK in member or setting. it dependents how to think the relations. ex. MemberSetting or SettingMember. if MemberSetting, FK will in member.member_id else if SettingMember, FK will in setting.member_id. it totally same result in query. how to think when relations. give me member settings, or thats setting of member.

```
member
--------
member_id PK FK
username

setting
--------
member_id PK
color
```

Comment: If they have the same PK, I wonder why they are two different tables.  Could `color` simply be  column in `member`?

Comment: @DaveCosta lets say, its 1 to many. member have many setting. thats why, theres split table. the question how u think to name it? where u put the FK in setting table or member table? because, in query, it same result.

Comment: @DaveCosta in simple word, member can reference to setting. and setting can reference to member too. it dependent on FK put it. but in query same result, right? or theres different.

Comment: If `member_id` is the PK of `setting`, there can't be multiple settings for the same member. PK is unique.

Comment: `setting.member_id` should just be a FK to `member`. The unique key should be `(member_id, color)`.

Comment: @Barmar so attribute only can 1 PK even in different table? member.member_id PK, setting.member_id PK? it only can be member.member_id PK, setting.member_id FK?

Comment: Each table has its own PK, and it has to be unique in that table.

Comment: @Barmar i know each table have own PK. cant setting.member_id to PK + FK?

Comment: If you do that it can't be 1-to-many, because you can't have more than 1 setting for the same `member_id`.

Comment: @juke part of the definition of PK is that it is unique.  If you specify `member_id` as a PK of the `setting` table, then you can only have at most 1 row for each member in that table.  Since you have said that "member have many setting", it does not make sense for `member_id` to be a PK of the `setting` table.

Comment: @Barmar my question is not that exactly. but FK in member or setting have different?

Comment: I think I'm having trouble understanding your poor English.

Comment: To query we do not need to know or declare FKs or other constraints. (If there is a FK or other constraint then more expressions work.) We declare a FK constraint to tell the DBMS that subrow values under some columns appear once each under some other columns.

Comment: This post is unintelligible. PS Clarify via edits, not comments. Ask a new question in a new post, not comments. Please research before considering posting a question.

Answer (score 0):

In a one-to-many relationship, the foreign key should be in the table on the "many" side of that relationship.

In your example, if it were similar to other databases where I found tables for `member` and `settings`, I would expect to see the foreign key in the `settings` table, because one member may have many settings. Not the other way around.

Demo:

```
create table member (
  member_id int primary key,
  username varchar(20) not null
);

create table settings (
  member_id int not null,
  setting varchar(20) not null,
  value varchar(64) not null,
  primary key (member_id, setting),
  foreign key (member_id) references member(member_id)
);
```

The above is a hypothetical example of how one could define the tables. By putting the foreign key in the `settings` table, it restricts rows of the `settings` table so that a row *must* exist in the `member` table with the same member_id value. But the opposite is not necessarily true; a member can exist even if it has zero rows in the `settings` table that reference it.

Comment: how about if foreign key in member? is there different? so member reference to setting not setting reference to member.

Comment: Yes, there is an important difference. That would mean a member can have only one setting. The value in the foreign key must reference a single value in a primary or unique key of the table it references. So it can point to only one row. I assume the purpose of the setting table is that it supports many settings for a given user. Otherwise you would just make a single column in the member table.

Comment: no one to one relations. but my question is FK in setting vs FK in member. there's different? i dont see theres difference in reference.

Comment: Okay, then it would mean a setting must exist before a member can reference it. Also the setting may exist without reference by any member.

Comment: so in my case, FK should in member.member_id? cause setting.member_id data that related to member will add later, right?

Comment: i think, i have two perspective in the way foreign key works. 1 in select query, 2 in insert query. if i put FK in member.member_id. Select query work but insert query not cause setting check member_id in member exist or not to put in setting.member_id. but if i put FK in setting.member_id. select and insert work. cause before select, should be insert first.

Comment: I would put the FK in the setting table, as I showed in my answer above.